MOK skipped on Ubuntu dual boot system
I'm a bit new to Ubuntu but I have to run some code specifically on Ubuntu 20.04. I have a Lenovo Ideapad L340 gaming + Nvidia GTX 1650 machine with Windows 11 and I dual booted Ubuntu 20.04.
Since I need to use the GPU, I went to "Software and Updates" then "Additional Drivers" and installed the most suitable nvidia driver.
I was then prompted for a MOK password which I entered and then rebooted my system. When presented with the MOK screen, I accidentally pressed boot instead of enrol password.
How can I force the MOK screen to come up again? I understand that the key is now probably discarded. Is there a way to make a new one specifically for my GPU? Should I reinstall the driver (if so, how) ?
Any help would be greatly appreciated!
